# How can I turn off Extension Download Errors?

Tags: wordpress, extension, error

Fresh install today of CiviCRM 4.7.9 on Wordpress.  There are no installed extensions and I don't need to install any extensions.  However—maybe due to how new the release is—I get this error message on *every* screen, *every time* I navigate anywhere in CiviCRM:

> "Extension download error Unable to download extension from
>   https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.9|cms=WordPress/single. Error
>   Message: Failed to connect to civicrm.org port 443: Connection timed
>   out"

[image]

This wasn't happening with the install of 4.7.8 I was working with just a few hours ago, on the same server. I am confident it can make external HTTP requests.

Can this error be fixed or, if not, at least turned off?  I don't currently need any extensions so I'm fine with CiviCRM (silently) failing to reach that URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do so, you need to add this following line on your civicrm.settings.php

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Extension Preferences']['ext_repo_url'] = false;
```

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions#Extensions-Disableautomaticinstallationsofextension